# Latest STS and git server

Tags: git, maven, debian, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Ho do i configure the latest STS to use my own git server?

My git server is installed on Debian Wheezy on a second pc and the GIT-Plugin from the STS uses my repository. But i can't commit an existing maven project.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thank you very much.

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Only the last step was missing.

I have to select my project in STS, right click and in popup menu select Team.
Next i've to select Share and then GIT.

That`s all.

Stefan